# In Azure DevOps, is there a way to quickly see what position a work item is on the backlog?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem

When viewing a specific Azure DevOps work item, I wish to know what priority the item is on the backlog.

It appears the only way to do this is to remember the work item number and find it on the Backlog. Is there something like a right click, view on backlog or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something like a right click, view on backlog or something
>   like that?

Pity to say, no, we haven't provide such feature which based on the items level between **Work items** and **Backlogs**.

Until now, we design **Boards** panel regard to the team or sprint level. So until now, we only provided the feature like View Boards in Backlog or View Backlog in Boards.

I know the method you were using is not convenient but I'm afraid it would be the most useful work around until now. Another work around I could used is using **filter** in backlogs to narrow down the work items displayed then you could quick to see which one is you are finding.

We are welcome you could share your idea, like right click to see one specific work item in Backlog, to our official community: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21). The product team will review these suggestions and consider about if we should expand it into azure devops product.